# Dropdown Render Issue with HTML and AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am having an issue with my dropdown menu. I have set it so that it populates on a click - but when it does not render normally. Please see the attached image ([http://imgur.com/a/0GiRZ](https://imgur.com/a/0GiRZ)). It requires a second click for the dropdown menu to expand.

This is my HTML code:

```
     <div class="form-group" ng-show="system.properties[0].value.target.connection.target_type === 'hive'">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="sdb">Database</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7" >
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="system.properties[0].value.target.connection.target_db" ng-click="db()">
                        <option ng-repeat="d in database" value={{d.name}}>{{d.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
     </div>
```

Angular:

```
// Calls DB preview
    $scope.db = function() {
        systemFactory.getDB(dbParam).then(function successCallback (result) {
            $scope.database = result.data.Data; 
        })          
    };
```

factory:

```
getDB: function(data) {                              
        var settings = {
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
            url: config.webserviceNonHTZ + "/getPreview",
            withCredentials: true
    };
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue - only thing that I can think of is ng-click. I tried using ng-change but that didn't fix the issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why `$scope.db` is a function and also an array?

Comment: Can you supply your systemFactory.getDB method?

Comment: Thanks @tanmay. I didn't realize I had them both named $scope.db. Changed it results name to $scope.database.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I've added the factory code

Comment: @Heather why to call `$scope.db` onclick? why can't you just have it in controller? it's async sitting inside controller anyway..

Comment: @tanmay I have it set to onclick b/c the dbparams being passed are dynamic (db list is based on the environment selected), so when the api call happenes on page load it will not have that parameter.

Comment: I am open to suggestions - doesn't have to be onclick

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code in `$timeout`:

```
$scope.db = function() {
        $timeout(function () {
            _loadFromDb(dbParam);
        })
    };

function _loadFromDb(dbParam) {
    systemFactory.getDB(dbParam).then(function successCallback (result) {
          $scope.database = result.data.Data; 
      })          
}
```

It will force `$digest` cycle and will redraw elements (remember to inject it, exactly as `$scope`) - cause maybe your way of loading data do not trigger it, btw how you get `dbParams`? btw 2: I really encourage you, if you have a possibility of course, to use `component`s or at least `controllerAs` syntax. It may be not possible with legacy code, but if you start new project you should try to avoid direct usage of `$scope`. **Or**, if it won't work, try to change

```
ng-show="system.properties[0].value.target.connection.target_type === 'hive'"
```

to

```
ng-if="system.properties[0].value.target.connection.target_type === 'hive'" ng-init="db()"
```

Of course, on `div class="form-group"`.`ng-if` will redraw element in HTML (with `ng-show` it's only not displayed) and call `db()` which will load data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will run into some odd behavior doing things the way that you are with populating the database list on the click of the select input element (in Chrome at least, if the select options change after the input is opened you will see up/down arrows and it will only be 1 row tall if there were no options and then options appear after it is already showing the select options).

I would recommend instead you listen for changes to your `target_type` property and load the databases when a change is detected. You can either do this with `ng-change` on the select element for the types or with `$scope.$watch` on that property. I created a [plunkr showing how to do each way](https://plnkr.co/edit/9qSaM5ruYOpWkyyyyNP6) (you'll notice that there are two versions to the plunkr).

Additionally, if you have other properties that the databases are dependent upon, you can set up something similar and look for changes for the other properties as well. This is just meant to show you some other options that will probably work better for you.

**Method 1: ng-change**

Add the `ng-change` attribute

```
<select ... ng-change="targetTypeChanged()">
    ...
</select>
```

Add the method to process the change

```
$scope.targetTypeChanged = function () {
    if ($scope.isHiveType()) {
        $scope.loadDatabases();
    }
};
```

**Method 2: $scope.$watch()**

Add the watch to the `$scope` property

```
$scope.$watch('connection.target_type', function () {
    if ($scope.isHiveType()) {
        $scope.loadDatabases();
    }
});
```

*Note: You will need to set up the property to watch on based on your `$scope` object structure. The example above is just using my plunkr setup.*